# Question about the test format applied in a for loop

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, procedural-programming

I have an issue with the following code. I am trying to remove the points which have a distance less than 2mm relative to each other starting with a specified point `frameCenter1`. The weird part is that in the second for loop when I apply `counter11 <= Length[b1[[All, 1]]]` as the test, it gives me the correct answer but when I run the `Bhn2 = Length[b1[[All, 1]]]` or `Length[b1]` earlier and substitute the value `Bhn2` as the test (i.e `counter11 <= Bhn2`) it gives me wrong answer with the following message `Part 7 of {{7,7},{8,5},{8,7},{7,6}} does not exist`. This should not happen as they are the same. I just substitute the value of the test (i.e Bhn2) instead of Length[b1[[All, 1]]].

```
dalist = {{9, 6}, {5, 6}, {6, 0}, {0, 5}, {10, 8}, {1, 2}, {10, 
4}, {1, 1}, {7, 7}, {6, 8}, {5, 3}, {6, 9}, {7, 4}, {1, 8}, {10, 
0}, {10, 7}, {6, 3}, {4, 0}, {9, 2}, {4, 7}, {1, 6}, {10, 8}, {7, 
8}, {0, 9}, {3, 4}, {0, 0}, {8, 5}, {4, 5}, {6, 0}, {2, 9}, {2, 
4}, {8, 4}, {7, 4}, {3, 6}, {7, 9}, {1, 9}, {1, 4}, {8, 0}, {8, 
9}, {5, 4}, {2, 5}, {2, 9}, {3, 1}, {0, 6}, {10, 3}, {9, 6}, {8, 
7}, {7, 6}, {7, 3}, {8, 9}, {7.5, 9}, {6.5, 9}, {7, 9}, {1, 
5}, {2, 6}, {1, 10}, {0.5, 8}, {1.5, 8}, {0.5, 7}, {1.5, 7}, {0.5,
 6}, {1.5, 6}, {0.5, 5}, {1.5, 5}, {0.5, 4}, {1.5, 4}, {0.5, 
9}, {1.5, 9}, {1, 7}, {2, 8}, {7, 10}, {9, 4}, {8, 4}, {8, 3}, {9,
 5}, {9, 3}, {7.5, 3}, {8.5, 3}, {9.5, 4}, {8.5, 4}, {9.5, 
4}, {7.5, 4}, {9.5, 4}}; 
Print[ListPlot[{dalist[[All, 1 ;; 2]]}, PlotStyle -> {Red}]]
Clear[b1, G1, S1, dataPnut2, Bhn, Bhn2, counter, counter1]
frameCenter1 = {{1, 10}, {7, 10}, {9, 4}}
Bhn = Length[frameCenter1]
counter0 = 1
For[counter = counter0, counter <= Bhn, counter++,
criticalRadius1 = 2;
b1 = Select[dalist, 
EuclideanDistance[#, frameCenter1[[counter]]] < criticalRadius1 &];
dataPnut2 = DeleteCases[dalist, Alternatives @@ b1];
Print[ListPlot[{dataPnut2[[All, 1 ;; 2]]}, PlotStyle -> {Blue}]];

 G1 = b1;
 Bhn2 = Length[b1];
 d1 = {};
 counter1 = 1;
 For[counter11 = counter1, counter11 <= Length[b1[[All, 1]]], 
  counter11++,
  b1 = Select[dataPnut2, 
    EuclideanDistance[#, b1[[counter11]]] < criticalRadius1 &];
  d1 = Join[d1, b1];
  ];
 S1 = Join[G1, d1];
 dataPnut2 = DeleteCases[dalist, Alternatives @@ S1];
 b1 = d1;
 dalist = dataPnut2;
 Print[ListPlot[{dataPnut2[[All, 1 ;; 2]]}, PlotStyle -> {Green}]]
 ]
```

Comment: Please fix the syntax errors in your code.

Comment: But I do not get syntax error in this code otherwise that I apply the aforementioned change in the question. (i.e  run Bhn2 = Length[b1[[All, 1]]] or Length[b1] earlier and substitute the value Bhn2 as the test (i.e counter11 <= Bhn2) in the 2nd for loop)

Comment: My question is why applying that change give the wrong result while they are the same.

Comment: Thank you! modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

To filter multiple `frameCenter`

```
filter[list_, criticalRadius_, frameCenter_] := 
 Select[list, EuclideanDistance[#, frameCenter] >= criticalRadius &]

frameCenters = {{1, 10}, {7, 10}, {9, 4}};
filter[dalist, criticalRadius, #] & /@ frameCenters
```

---

Is there are reason for wanting to do this procedurally? A functional solution is much shorter and easier to understand.

To remove all points that are closer than some distance from a given point you could do this.

```
frameCenter = {1, 10};
criticalRadius = 2;

Select[dalist, EuclideanDistance[#, frameCenter] >= criticalRadius &]
```

For multiple `frameCenter` values, just wrap the above in a function and `Map` over the list of `frameCenter` values.

Comment: Thank you! It is just part of my routine. Could you please explain how I can wrap it in a function. Can I define select as a function?                                                        
   Select[dalist, EuclideanDistance[#, frameCenter1] >= 2 &] & /@ {{1, 
   10}, {7, 10}, {9, 4}}                                                                                                                I am confused as the variables are fed from framecenter1 and dalist.

Comment: @MehdiEbadi Updated answer to show how to wrap the Select in a function and Map.